# symfony2 config.php error 500 response

Tags: php, symfony

When I try to access config.php after a clean symfony install, it trhows an internal server error (500)

More info:

- Permissions are set with ACL and I can access app_dev.php and app.php without any issues.
- The symfony installation is on a virtual machine with Ubuntu server 14.04.
- Already added to config.php my own ip in the localhost condition:

  ```
  if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
      '127.0.0.1',
      '192.168.56.1',
      '192.186.56.3',
      '::1',))) 
  {
      header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
      exit('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
  }
  ```
- Tried to set config.php permissions to 777 with no success

Comment: Time to read error logs.

Comment: indeed, was a comment without /

Thanks :) newbie tinghs

Comment: If there error was inside the code above, then you would have **403** error instead of **500**

Answer (score 0):

Was just a syntax error in the cofig.php, var/log/apache2/error.log had the answer.